# Change quantity for products

Tags: java, android, listview

I have an app where I have a `ListView` with three columns. `ListView Adapter` is populated with data from `Firebase`(**product name, price, quantity**). Data to `firebase` is sent from another `activity`

But in my `ListView` I want the third column, which is quantity, to add a `NumberPicker` to choose the quantity for each product. I also want, for example, if in `firebase` there is an available `quantity : 3` and the user select `4`, an an error message to appear saying something like `quantity not available`.

**Code for object class:**

```
public class Produse {

public String produsId;
public String produs;
public String pret;
public String cantitate;

public Produse(){

}

public Produse(String produsId, String produs, String pret, String cantitate) {
    this.produsId = produsId;
    this.produs = produs;
    this.pret = pret;
    this.cantitate = cantitate;
}

public String getProdusId() {
    return produsId;
}

public String getProdus() {
    return produs;
}

public String getPret() {
    return pret;
}

public String getCantitate() {
    return cantitate;
}
}
```

**Code for ListView Adapter**

```
public class ProduseList extends ArrayAdapter<Produse> {

private Activity context;
private List<Produse> produseList;


public ProduseList(Activity context, List<Produse> produseList) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_layout, produseList);
    this.context = context;
    this.produseList = produseList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null, true);

    TextView textViewProdus = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewProdus);
    TextView textViewPret = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPret);
    TextView textViewCantitate = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCantitate);

    Produse produse = produseList.get(position);

    textViewProdus.setText(produse.getProdus());
    textViewPret.setText(produse.getPret());
    textViewCantitate.setText(produse.getCantitate());


    return listViewItem;
}
}
```

**And layout for columns:**

```
  <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewProdus"
    android:layout_width="115dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:text="Produs"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textSize="14.5dp"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewPret"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:text="Suma"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>



<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textViewCantitate"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="2.5dp"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
    android:text="0"
    android:textAppearance="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Headline"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:padding="7dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"/>
```

In my code **product name = produs, price = pret and quantity = cantitate**.

Hope guys you understand I really count on you.

Comment: Firebase has callbacks that you could grab the data you need to change the quantities if thats what you mean

Comment: Do you have some examples? Or links?

Answer (score 0):

try below code, you should edit code like "key quantity product" you stored on firebase.

```
    public class ProduseList extends ArrayAdapter<Produse> {

    private Activity context;
    private List<Produse> produseList;


    public ProduseList(Activity context, List<Produse> produseList) {
        super(context, R.layout.list_layout, produseList);
        this.context = context;
        this.produseList = produseList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();

        View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_layout, null, true);

        TextView textViewProdus = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewProdus);
        TextView textViewPret = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPret);
        final NumberPicker numCantitate = (NumberPicker) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewCantitate);

        Produse produse = produseList.get(position);

        textViewProdus.setText(produse.getProdus());
        textViewPret.setText(produse.getPret());
        numCantitate.setMaxValue(100);
        numCantitate.setMinValue(0);
        numCantitate.setWrapSelectorWheel(true);
        //Set a value change listener for NumberPicker
        numCantitate.setOnValueChangedListener(new NumberPicker.OnValueChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onValueChange(NumberPicker picker, final int oldVal, final int newVal){
                //get your valid quantity from firebase server 
                // Get a reference to our posts
                final FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                DatabaseReference ref = database.getReference("server/saving-data/quantity/product");

                // Attach a listener to read the data at our posts reference
                ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        int validQuantity = dataSnapshot.getValue(Integer.class);
                        if(newVal <= validQuantity){
                            //Display the newly selected number from picker
                            numCantitate.setValue(newVal); 
                        }else {
                            numCantitate.setValue(oldVal);
                            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Wrong quantity.....", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        System.out.println("The read failed: " + databaseError.getCode());
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        return listViewItem;
    }
}
```

Comment: i don't know, now i get an error ` java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference`